# Symfony - Which link was clicked

Tags: symfony

I am building simple car renting app in Symfony for a programming class at my university.

The problem I don't know how to solve is as fallows:

Form database query I get list of available cars and I display them easily using twig template.

I want a button next to each listed car that links to /rent site where user provides all the required information.

I know I can use something like that:

```
 <a href="{{ path('rent', {'id': car.id}) }}">
```

But is there any other way for controller responsible for this route to know which link was clicked? After all I need to know which car user wants to rent, and I don't want to end up with url /rent/{id}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that a few other solutions were already provided, but I wanted to give a little more explanation along with a slightly different suggestion. Pipe's response is on the right track and works, but for your purposes I wouldn't just generate a random token per car, I would have a [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) tied to each car that is SEO-friendly.

For example in your car table, you would have:

```
+-------+--------------+
|  id   |    slug      |
+-------+--------------+
|   1   | ford-150     |
|   2   | cadillac-cts |
+-------+--------------+
```

Then your entity would have the corresponding variables and Doctrine annotations that would look something like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Car
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $slug;
}
```

Now the link you generate in your Twig would look like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('rent', {'slug': car.slug}) }}">
```

Then your controller/route could be defined as such:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class RentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/rent/{slug}", name="rent")
     */
    public function rentAction(Car $car)
    {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Here Symfony uses the [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) along with your `Car $car` [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to automatically use that `slug` property and find the corresponding `Car` entity that matches that slug.

It is essentially a shortcut for the following, which you could also do instead of using the param converter:

```
/**
 * @Route("/rent/{slug}")
 */
public function rentAction($slug)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $car = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Car')->findOneBySlug($slug);

    // ...
}
```

This will allow you to keep a friendly URL that makes sense to the user while also hides the ID entirely.

Comment: Thank you, perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the car.id on the URL, create a random "token" for each car and make the url like:

```html
<a href="{{ path('rent', {'id': car.token}) }}">
```

That would be `/rent/abcd5437fbadce88`